# How to split text from file into words?

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the text from a file and split it into words by removing spaces and other symbols. This is part of my code for handling the file:

```
void addtext(char wordarray[M][N])
{
    FILE *fileinput;
    char word[N];
    char filename[N];
    char *pch;
    int i=0;
    printf("Input the name of the text file(ex \"test.txt\"):\n");
    scanf("%19s", filename);
    if ((fileinput = fopen(filename, "rt"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    while (fgets(word, N, fileinput)!= NULL)
    {
       pch = strtok (word," ,'.`:-?");
       while (pch != NULL)
       {
         strcpy(wordarray[i++], pch);
         pch = strtok (NULL, " ,'.`:-?");
       }

    }
    fclose(fileinput);
    wordarray[i][0]='\0';
    return ;
}
```

But here is the issue. When the text input from the file is:

`Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank.`

Then the output when I try to print it is this:

```
Alice
was
beginning
to
get
very
tired
of
sitting
by
her
s
ister
on
the
bank
```

As you can see, the word "sister" is split into 2. This happens quite a few times when adding a bigger text file. What am I missing?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Comment: Yeah, I was testing something and forgot to remove it. This isn't the issue though

Comment: please show the values of `N` and `M`.

Comment: M is 1000 and N is 20

Comment: This site might help you: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/14213/how-to-play-with-strings-in-c/string-split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you count the characters you'll see that `s` is the `57th` character. `57` is `19` times `3` which is the number of parsed characters in each cycle, (`20 -1`, as `fgets` null terminates the string and leaves the `20th` character in the buffer).

As you are reading lines in batches of `19` characters, the line will be cuted every multiple of `19` charater and the rest will be read by the next `fgets` in the cycle.

The first two times you where lucky enough that the line was cutted at a space, character `19` at the end of `beggining`, character `38` at the end of `tired`, the third time it was in the midle of `sister` so it cuted it in two words.

Two possible fixes:

- Replace:

  ```
  while (fgets(word, N, fileinput)!= NULL)
  ```

  With:

  ```
  while (fscanf(fileinput, %19s, word)  == 1)
  ```

  Provided that there are no words larger than `19` in the file, which is the case.
- Make `word` large enough to take whole the line:

  ```
  char word[80];
  ```

  `80` should be enough for the sample line.

Comment: N is indeed 19. Then the problem is the N in fgets as I thought. Can this be fixed or should I try a different approach?

Comment: @JoeDurner, yes, it's easily fixable, you can simply make `word` be large enough to get the whole line.

Comment: @JoeDurner  added 2 possible solutions to the answer.

Comment: Both of those seem to be working, but fscanf does seem to be working better. Wanted to avoid it at first since I already used in and wanted to experiment. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @JoeDurner good mindset, experimenting is a great way of learning, I'll note that as a general rule, `fgets` is better, but in this particular case `fscanf` does seem to be a better option, as always, it's a matter of picking the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

You are missing that a single `fgets` call at maximum will read N-1 characters from the file, Consequently the buffer `word` may contain only the first part of a word. For instance it seems that in your case the `s` from the word `sister` was read by one `fgets` call and that the remaining part, i.e. `ister` was read by the next `fgets` call. Consequently, your code detected `sister` as two words.

So you need to add code that can check whether the end of the is a whole word or a part of a word.

To start with you can increase N to a higher number but to make it work in general you must add code that checks the end of the `word` buffer.

Also notice that long words may require more than 2 `fgets` call.

As a simple alternative to `fgets` and `strtok` consider `fread` and a simple char-by-char passing of the input.

Below is a simple, low-performance example of how it can be done.

```
int isdelim(char c)
{
  if (c == '\n') return 1;
  if (c == ' ') return 1;
  if (c == '.') return 1;
  return 0;
}

void addtext(void)
{
    FILE *fileinput;
    char *filename = "test.txt";

    if ((fileinput = fopen(filename, "rt"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open file\n");
        return;
    }

    char c;
    int state = LOOK_FOR_WORD;
    while (fread(&c, 1, 1, fileinput) == 1)
    {
      if (state == LOOK_FOR_WORD)
      {
        if (isdelim(c))
        {
          // Nothing to do.. keep looking for next word
        }
        else
        {
          // A new word starts
          putchar(c);
          state = READING_WORD;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if (isdelim(c))
        {
          // Current word ended
          putchar('\n');
          state = LOOK_FOR_WORD;

        }
        else
        {
          // Current word continues
          putchar(c);
        }
      }
    }

    fclose(fileinput);
    return ;
}
```

To keep the code simple it prints the words using `putchar` instead of saving them in an array but that is quite easy to change.

Further, the code only reads one char at the time from the file. Again it's quit easy to change the code and read bigger chunks from the file.

Likewise you can add more delimiters to `isdelim` as you like (and improve the implementation)